# why onlick function in button tag not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, django, dom, onclick

I have created a delete Photo button which works as if we click on it a another delete button appear in somewhere in code , the code is

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="showdel()">Delete Photo</button>
```

after that I created div element where that delete button should be created .

```
<div id="del"></div>
```

and function for this is .

```
function showdel(){
    var div = document.getElementById('del');
    div.innerHTML = '<center><button class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button></center>';
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Just recreated everything of yours here and its working do check.
https://codepen.io/jiteshdhamaniya/pen/abNNazY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="showdel()">Delete Photo</button>

<div id="del">
</div>

function showdel(){

    document.getElementByID("del").style.visibilty="hidden"

}
```

Comment: so is there any way that it can access the other div

Comment: Yeah. Just format the code as I have shown and that'll be it.

Comment: But I can't place the button there then any way there ?